# How to get the past 2 days data from Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

past 2 day get data from mongodb

var total_user = await User.find({ "createdAt": { $lte: new Date(new Date() - 1000 * 86400 * 2) } })

I am using moongoose in node js any if do you have any aggreation how to do it

```
var total_user = await User.find({ "createdAt": { $lte: new Date(new Date() - 1000 * 86400 * 2) } })
```

Comment: `$lte: new Date(new Date() - 1000 * 86400 * 2)` mean before 2 days ago, yes? Is there an error?  Not getting the expected response?  What is `total_user` after the call?  Does the collection have any documents where `"createdAt"` is before 2 days ago?

Comment: Just to be clear about it, @rickhg12hs is saying (and I agree) that you are looking for all documents that are **older** than 2 days. According to your title you want to use `$gte` instead of `$lte` in order to find documents that were created in the past 2 days.